# using (this) with dynamic content jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trouble understanding the addition of dynamic content with jQuery. My code will prepend items to a list and when you click an item on that list, the contents of that item should be visible. At the moment, when I click an item, the contents of all items are displayed. I tried adding (this) but that doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var hidden = true;

$("#add").click(function() {
    var item = $("#name").val();
    var date = $("#date").val();

    if(item == "") {
        return false;
    }

    var prependItem =
    "<li class='new'>"+
        "<button class='btn btn-default' id='check'></button>"+
        "<span class='item'>&nbsp;"+item+"</span>"+
        "<ul class='sub'>"+
            "<li>"+
                "Due date: 5/3/2015"+
            "</li>"+
        "</ul>"+
    "</li>";

    $(".todo").prepend(prependItem);
    $(".sub").hide();
    $(".form")[0].reset();

    return false;
});

// show sub content
$(".todo").on("click", ".item", function() {
    if(hidden == true) {
        $(".sub").show();
        hidden = false;
    }
    else {
        $(".sub").hide();
        hidden = true;
    }
});

$(".todo").on("click", "#check", function() {
    // line through
})                                      
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.sub` element is a sibling of the `.item`, so as well at using `this` to get a reference to the element which raised the event, you need to use `siblings('.sub')`. You can also simplify the code by using `toggle()`. Try this:

```
$(".todo").on("click", ".item", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".sub").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sub` is the next sibling of the clicked `item` so you could use `this` along with [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) like

```
// show sub content
$(".todo").on("click", ".item", function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Also instead of using a variable to store the hidden state use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(".todo").on("click", ".item", function() {
    $(this).children(".sub").toggle();
});
```